# Should multiple return values be used for Try...() style functions?

Tags: c#, .net

This is a code style question so I am really after opinions.

Now that C# has multiple return values, should the `bool TrySomething(..., out T result)` pattern that is familiar to .NET developers be updated to `(bool, T) TrySomething(...)`?  I can't make up my mind.

Comment: What do you see as the pro's and con's?

Comment: @n8wrl That's a good question, I suppose from my point of view: out params are a bit more fiddly (although not so much with inline declaration) on the other hand the existing pattern is familiar.

Comment: Are you asking if existing functions should be changed, or what the best practice is for writing new functions?

Comment: Thank you @EricLippert! I don't think we can or should change existing functions - too much would break. I am on the fence too - the existing pattern is familiar. Not sure how I'd write better code with the (bool, T) pattern replacing out T.

Comment: @EricLippert New functions.  I don't think it's realistic to expect existing functions to be changed.  I guess that's part of the problem - should we remain consistent with what has already been written, or take advantage of a new feature.

Comment: I don't think `if (TrySomething().Item1)` would improve readability if you ask me

Comment: I note that C# has also recently added the ability to put "out" variable declarations in-line with the expression. Does that influence your opinion?

Comment: @EricLippert Actually it does - see my first response to n8wrl

Comment: I've been trying to remember the name of the feature @EricLippert is referring to. To me, that with the (...out T result) syntax results in cleaner more familiar code.

Comment: It is very difficult to correctly use out parameters in LINQ queries but easy to use tuples correctly; does *that* influence your opinion?

Comment: Hadn't thought about that at all! That's why this is such a wonderful community...

Comment: Hmm, yes.  Perhaps we should create overloads to support both styles!

Comment: For a LINQ-targeted function I guess I'd prefer to return a NULLable so I could coalesce it with an empty list! Of course that might hide a failure...

Comment: @jamesmus hope you know who is clarifying your doubts.

Comment: And @RudreshaParameshappa doesn't mean me :)

Comment: @RudreshaParameshappa Of course ;-)

Comment: Suppose for example we have a list of strings, some of them are numbers, and we want the list of strings with just the numbers, still as strings, but in numeric order. Do you see why the completely natural way to write it `int i; var q = from s in new[] { "21", "2", "201", "hello" }
       where int.TryParse(s, out i)
       orderby i
       select s;` is wrong? Can you predict the sequence that the query produces when enumerated?  If you had a `TryParse` that returned a tuple (or nullable int), this wouldn't happen.

Comment: @EricLippert I just executed code by initializing **i to 0**. Why orderby is not working? I am struggling to understand

Comment: @RudreshaParameshappa Because the order by is evaluated after the last call to TryParse and so i == 0 for all elements in the resulting set (there is only one value for i at a given point in time).

Comment: @RudreshaParameshappa: Think about it like this: the query is the same as `var q1 = from s in ... where ... select s; var q2 = q1.ToArray(); var q = from s in q2 orderby i select s;`  By the time the third query runs, `i` is zero because that's the last value it had.  An `orderby` does the moral equivalent of a `ToArray()` because it needs to know the *entire result set of the query so far* to sort it, so any side effects of the first half of the query are *all* done by the time the second half of the query reads `i`.

Comment: (And yes, you need to initialize `i` because if the query has no elements, then `i` is never initialized at all, but it is read in the orderby. The compiler is smart enough to realize that `i` is uninitialized in that scenario, but not smart enough to realize that if we're in that scenario, the `orderby` never runs either.)